# Dynamically add created images to asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, phantomjs

i have a rails app that creates images in a controller with phantomjs using

```
system("/usr/bin/phantomjs ./app/assets/javascripts/phantom_snapshot.js  http://urlToPageWhereImgComesFrom/ ./app/assets/images/newImage.png '#divId'&")
```

Now I want to integrate that image in a view, but I think because of assets:precompile the image is not yet available. Is this the correct location to put my images anyway? Or is there a way to dynamically add the created image to my assets?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you want to put it in `./public/assets/images/`. Thats where static assets which do not get precompiled go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static assets which will not be precompiled go in the `./public` folder.

Just make sure you have static asset serving turned on in your environment

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```